# Adding Multiple Multi Selects

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Basically I already have the code to pull back all orders with same prefix but is there a way I can add in the option of a multi select of ordernames in SSRS so I need to change my code too. i.e. Although the code already can pull back orders that have ABC prefix, I want the ability to also by order name be able to pull many back. With the first version only any policies that have the order prefix  would appear but I want all orders with Order name of Amy Jane or Betty Jane

I'm currently trying

```
DECLARE @order varchar (100)
set @order = 'Amy Jane' or 'Betty Jane'

SELECT OrderNoref,
OrderDate
FROM Ordertable
WHERE LEFT([OrderNoref],(SELECT MAX(LEN(OrderPrefix)) FROM Orders123 WHERE OrderName = @order)) IN (SELECT OrderPrefixFROM Orders123  WHERE OrderName= @order)
```

I'm wanting something like the following but I'm having issues

```
SELECT  OrderNoref,
OrderDate
FROM Ordertable
WHERE LEFT([OrderNoref],(SELECT MAX(LEN(OrderPrefix)) FROM Orders123 WHERE OrderName = @order)) IN (SELECT OrderPrefixFROM Orders123  WHERE OrderName= @order)
AND (Select OrderName from Orders123) in (@Order)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help the explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below, I've changed 'AND' to OR and corrected the syntax. 
This will filter data using order name or order prefix

```
    SELECT 
        OP.OrderName, 
        O.OrderNo,
        O.OrderDate
    FROM Ordertablev AS O
    JOIN (
            SELECT OrderPrefix, OrderName FROM Orders123  WHERE OrderName= 'Amy Jane' OR OrderName = 'Betty Jane'
        ) AS OP ON LEFT(O.OrderNo, LEN(OP.OrderPrefix)) = OP.OrderPrefix
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake ordername is only is orders123 table

Comment: Thanks you that works I just need to add in my parameter instead of the names as in